# V8 electric engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, automotive-engineering, electric-vehicles

For a while I have thought it would be interesting if someone could develop a 'reciprocating electric' engine.  It would use the same principle as maglev trains to move a magnet up and down in a reciprocating motion, driving a crankshaft via connecting rods. I don't know if it would have any advantage over a pure rotary electric motor, perhaps the ability to control torque better. Also the power stroke can be in both the up and down directions. The biggest advantage is that it would give electric motors 'character' and 'coolness' in the same way car enthusiasts compare the various engine configurations of internal combustion engines (V8, V6, Flat 6, etc).  Does anyone know if this has been developed?  If not this could be a good college engineering project or masters thesis.

Comment: First, welcome to Engineering.SE. This question is really too broad to answer. Something like this is possible (in that anything is possible), but it completely eliminates most of the benefits of an electric motor. As such, the question falls into the "prove this idea" area which leads to quickly changing parameters as objections are raised.

Comment: To clarify hazzey's comment - this is too broad for us to *usefully answer within the context of our site*. For related discussions, see [this](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/311/368) and [this](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/188/368) discussion on our Meta site.

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly possible as each cylinder could effectively be a solenoid (i'm actually pretty sure I have seen exactly this but can't remember where atm) ....however the reciprocating nature of IC engines is one of their big disadvantages as it introduces inherent  vibration and puts big transient loads on certain parts (especially connecting rods). In comparison the rotor of an electric motor is a much more desirable state of affairs from a mechanical perspective.

In fact, from a performance perspective, if you put aside to problems of power density for mobile electric power, you would go for electric motors over reciprocating engines every time as they are quite, light, simple and have flat torque curves.

If you want V8 sound it is better to just have a V8 soundtrack and speakers.

As you say this would be an excellent Mech or Electrical Engineering undergraduate project.

Edit yes, this is a thing [V8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HND4x22jXM) (link to youtube video) and [V12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhYEdD94vH0)

Comment: That's a cool demonstration. I bet it would be a fun project indeed.

Comment: Yean fundamentally failry simple but with plenty of scope for tweaking. Definitely better than the bizarre group project I got foisted on me in my degree :P

Comment: I think this should be left open. It is well defined enough to be answered concisely and even answers of 'no this is a stupid idea because...are informative.' also it has actually been done which definitely makes it fair game for an engineering question.

Comment: @ChrisJohns Not all interesting questions are a good fit for the site.  This is a good example of an interesting question that is simply too broad for the StackExchange Q&A format.  Think through how multiple answers could focus on completely separate portions of the question.  While all the answers may be useful information, it really doesn't fit within how the Q&A format is supposed to work.